# SEO URL for information pages in opencart not working

Tags: url, seo, opencart

I'm trying to create custom SEO url's for opencart i've googled for hours and tried all the solutions (Set SEO friendly urls to yes in the admin pannel) and succesfully added SEO keywords to my information pages. Yet im still getting `/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=11` instead of `/media/` also going to `/media/`give me a 404 error.

The odd thing is that my catelog pages are working correctly and will just give me an url like `/myshop/` i've added my htaccess file if that is any help.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: Do You have Your OpenCart installed in the web root or in the subdirectory?

Comment: Try removing just the `RewriteBase /` and see if that fixes it

Comment: its in my main directory so rewritebase / should work, tried removing it aswell didn't solve it.

Comment: Sorry the removing of rewrite base solved my issue just have to change the hyperlink references, your a champ make it into an answer an ill accept it.

Comment: @JayGilford Removing `RewriteBase`? I thought it is quite necessary... Will remember that...

Comment: @shadyyx - quite the opposite in fact. It is on some servers, but most are fine. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when apache reads the RewriteBase directive it gets confused rather than helped so it's worth checking to see if removing it fixes the URL's. This is something I generally remove as it will usually work even with a subdirectory such as having your store in `/store/` on your domain as it's pretty clever at working out if it needs to be resolved or not