# Custom SEO URL of Product page in opencart 2.x

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, opencart2.x

I am looking for some help on writing custom dynamic SEO URLS for my product and category pages in opencart 2.x

I want to achieve `www.example.com/my-keyword/product-name-keyword/` and for category `www.example.com/my-cat-keyword/cat-name-keyword/`

I tried modifying the code in (`/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`) as below and the URL is being generated in the front-end but when I click on the product name / image it gives 404.

```
                if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                    $url .= '/product/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }
```

Here is my htaccess.

```
    # 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

# RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: Did you try also updating your rewrite rules? I'm pretty sure you're going to have to do both.

Comment: I am using standard set of rules at the moment

Comment: @user963705 question asked too many times :(, u tried this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958835/seo-url-for-information-pages-in-opencart-not-working) or you updated/ renamed your htaccess file ? are you checking this on localhost ? your setup is subdomain or not ?

Comment: @user5419232 this doesn't resolved my issue. I am still been able to generate the url on product on category pages but when I clock on the urls it gives soft 404.

Comment: Here is the category page for reference : [link](http://goo.gl/i4Z2VA)
And the product url :  [link](http://goo.gl/YfWl7k)

Comment: @user963705 can you add htaccess file or print screen of file ?

Comment: @user5419232 I have updated my post with the htaccess file. Can you please check if there is anything i am missing

Answer (score 0):

This is the only code you have to update or any else which faces this kind of problem (mostly)

```
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

# RewriteBase /
```

uncomment this line and add your Opencart path if you have any and you have (i checked in your link). So it will be

```
Rewritebase /projects/bnw-collections/alpha/
```

and rename your htaccess.txt to .htaccess  . Hope this will help.