# Opencart 3 .x SEO Url not working for route=information/contact, route=account/login

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, opencart-3

**opencart 3 .x SEO URL issue**

In opencart 3 .x SEO URL Working for product id, category id, information id but for page common/home, account/login, account/account etc not working.

**i had changed it from htaccess.txt to .htaccess**

**Change from System > Setting > Server**

[image]

**i m adding in SEO url from admin in Design > SEO Url**

[image]

Still not working

Can you help me guys.

Thank You,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEO URL for information pages in opencart not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958835/seo-url-for-information-pages-in-opencart-not-working)

Comment: no i check that not that reason.

Answer (score 5):

**Opencart 3.x SEO URL issue SOLVED Just Upload extension or follow this steps.**

its working fine for product_id, category_id etc...

but for any pages its not working

**For Fix with Extension Click Here**

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31993

**OR**

**THIS STEPS ARE FOR DEVELOPERS ONLY FOR WHOM DON'T WANT TO INSTALL PLUGIN**

now i m going to see you how we fix that opencart 3.x seo issue.

step 1 - open your ftp and go to this path catalog/controller/startup

step 2 - open seo_url.php for edit

step 3 - line no 87 we have to put one more else if

code :

```
} elseif ($key == 'route') {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($value) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
$url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
unset($data[$key]);
} else if ($data['route'] == "common/home") {
$url .= '/';
}
```

end code :

step 4 - rename .htaccess.txt to .htaccess

**THIS VIDEO FOR DEVELOPERS ONLY**

https://youtu.be/bS1N_twvL4o

Any Theme Compatible.

Frontend Demo

http://demo.sainent.com

Admin Demo

http://demo.sainent.com/admin

Username: demo

Password: demo

Comment: yes its working if you had any issue then you can ask for support in opencart.com check extension link and click on support https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31993

Comment: Why this is not fixed by Opencart?

Answer (score -1):

Just rename .htaccess.txt to .htaccess in your installation dir.